# JUnit : Is there a way to skip a test belonging to a Test class's parent?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have two classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoobar { ... }
```

and

```
public class ConcreteFoobar extends AbstractFoobar { ... }
```

I have corresponding test classes for these two classes:

```
public class AbstractFoobarTest { ... }
```

and

```
public class ConcreteFoobarTest extends AbstractFoobarTest { ... }
```

When I run ConcreteFoobarTest (in JUnit), the annotated @Test methods in AbstractFoobarTest get run along with those declared directly on ConcreteFoobarTest because they are inherited.

Is there anyway to skip them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Misunderstood the Question**

1. Make `AbstractFoobarTest` abstract.
   That way the test methods in
   `AbstractFoobarTest` are only run
   once, when `ConcreteFoobarTest` is
   executed. You are going to need a
   concrete subclass to test the
   methods in `AbstractFoobar` anyway.
2. Or just remove the inheritance
   between `AbstractFoobartest` and
   `ConcreteFoobarTest`. You don't want
   to make use of it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, making the parent test class abstract did the trick! (your earlier @ignore tip worked as well, but I like this one better.)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need `AbstractFoobarTest` in the first place because after all you can't create an instance of the abstract class, so, you will still rely on your concrete class to test your abstract class.

That means, you will end up using your `ConcreteFoobarTest` will test the APIs from the abstract class. Thus, you will have just this:-

```
public class ConcreteFoobarTest  { ... 
   @Test
   public void testOne() {
      ConcreteFoobar cf = new ConcreteFoobar();
      // assert cf.conreteAPI();
   }

   @Test
   public void testTwo() {
      ConcreteFoobar cf = new ConcreteFoobar();
      // assert cf.abstractClassAPI();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using process tags would allow you to run into specific bodies of code